# Installing SCCM Client 2012 failed: "CcmSetup failed with error code 0x80004002"

Tags: windows-xp, sccm, sccm-2012, bits

We're using Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager 2012. And I have issues installing the SCCM Client on a Windows XP Prof SP3 PC. The Log on the XP machine says:

```
Failed to query BITS 2.5 interface with error 0x80004002    ccmsetup    22.10.2014 15:46:34 268 (0x010C)  
This operating system does not contain the correct version of BITS. BITS 2.5 or later is required.  ccmsetup    22.10.2014 15:46:34 268 (0x010C)  
A Fallback Status Point has not been specified.  Message with STATEID='321' will not be sent.   ccmsetup    22.10.2014 15:46:34 268 (0x010C)  
CcmSetup failed with error code 0x80004002  ccmsetup    22.10.2014 15:46:34 1448 (0x05A8)
```

BITS service is running and as far as I can see it is the correct version (qmgr.dll and qmgrprxy.dll are version 6.7.*). Windows Update (which uses BITS) does work without problems.

Some sites are telling to install KB923845 but this update says, there is already a newer version installed.

Does someone know how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have an older version of the SCCM client installed on this machine?  If so, manually uninstall it before attempting to install a newer version.

Comment: No, there was never this or another version of SCCM Client installed on this PC.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but in case it helps others. I had this same issue. I ended up getting the Bitsadmin.exe from the Vista Service Pack 1 (extracted it from one of the cabs in the SP). Running Bitsadmin /util /version /verbose returned an error for the  IBackgroundCopyJobHttpOptions interface. 
I checked the bits files to ensure they were the correct versions as listed:
File version for BITS binaries:

- file path version langId
- C:\WINDOWS\system32\qmgr.dll 6.7.2600.5512 1033
- C:\WINDOWS\system32\qmgrprxy.dll 6.7.2600.5512 1033
- C:\WINDOWS\system32\bitsprx2.dll 6.7.2600.5512 1033
- C:\WINDOWS\system32\bitsprx3.dll 6.7.2600.5512 1033
- C:\WINDOWS\system32\bitsprx4.dll 6.7.2600.5512 1033

These were all correct, so i reregistered each file:

C:\Temp>regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\bitsprx2.dll

C:\Temp>regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\bitsprx3.dll

C:\Temp>regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\bitsprx4.dll

C:\Temp>regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\qmgr.dll

C:\Temp>regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\qmgrprxy.dll

after reregistering these dlls, running Bitsadmin again showed no errors, and the SCCM client installed successfully. No restart was required. 
Hope this helps!